# Exception in Data table ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, jsp, datatable

I have one JSP in spring project. I used to get the All the employee details using data table by Ajax. But i got exception while loading the page. Here is my JSP, model and controller method. Correct my mistake.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>User and Employee Management</title>
// Required script and Css link
</head>
<body>
<div class="generic-container" style="width:97%; height:95%;">
    <%@include file="authheader.jsp" %> 
    <div class="panel panel-default">
          <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">All Employees</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">Employee Details </span>
    </div>
    <div style="height:70%;overflow:auto;">
        <table class="table table-hover"  style="overflow-x:auto" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Reference Id</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Employee Designation</th>
                    <th>Employee Salary</th>
                    <th>Address</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                        function() {
                            $("#example").DataTable({
                                                scrollY:        280,
                                                scrollCollapse: true,
                                                paging:         true,
                                                "sAjaxSource" : "getEmployees",
                                                "aoColumns" : [
                                                        {
                                                            "mData" : "employeeReferenceId"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "mData" : "employeeName"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "mData" : "employeeDesg"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "mData" : "salary"
                                                        },{
                                                            "mData" : "address.address"
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                            });
                        });
        </script>
```

Model: Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private int id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
private String employeeName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_DESG")
private String employeeDesg;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "SALARY")
private String salary;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_REFERENCE_ID")
private String employeeReferenceId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Model: Address

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

@Id
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name="emp_id",insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private int employeeId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)

@JoinColumn(name="emp_id",referencedColumnName="employee_id")
private Employee employee;
//Getters and Setters
}
```

And controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/getEmployees" })
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getEmployees(ModelMap model) {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<Employee> employees=employeeService.findAllEmployees();
    data.put("data", employees);
    return data;
}
```

And the Error is

```
Apr 13, 2017 5:58:25 PM 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver 
handleHttpMessageNotWritable
WARNING: Failed to write HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could 
not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role
```

Comment: There should be caused by stacktrace entry too. That will tell what exactly is happening. It seems like you have role collection somewhere on some entity and something is not right with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why getting this exception is entity configuration. Because the JSON is mapping the parent entity with child entity. Since you have configured the child entity with the relation parent entity. Hence, you are getting nested exception.

Employee --> Address (Again Employee configured in Child entity). Can ignore this issue with the following annotation in Address object.

```
@JSONIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="emp_id",referencedColumnName="employee_id")
private Employee employee;
```

@JSONIgnore annotation will prevent the nested exception when returning JSON Object.